# Unable to transfer large size file using request module in Node.js

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, node-request, filestreams

In a Node.js project I have to transfer file from computer to server. I can send file if file size is small i.e. 2mb but unable to send file if it is more than this size. Here is my code as follows:

```
var url1 = 'http://beta.xxxxx.com/Xbox/xxxx/index.php/info/xxxxx';
var csvenriched = APPDATApath+'/xxxx/users/'+userId+'/programs/'+programName+'/'+foldername+'/Data_'+tmpstmp+'.csv';

var req = request.post(url1, function (err, resp, body1) {  
    if (err) {
        console.log('REQUEST RESULTS:'+err+resp.statusCode+body1);
        res.send(err); return false;
    } else {
        res.send(body1); return false;
    }
});

var form = req.form();

form.append('file', fs.createReadStream(csvenriched));
```

On the PHP side where I am sending data code is as follows:

```
public function actionSavetestvideo() {
    if (!empty($_FILES)) {
        $path = Yii::$app->basePath.'/testfiles/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $path)) {
            return 'uploaded';
        } else {
            return 'error'.$_FILES["file"]["error"];
        }
    } else {
        return $_FILES;
    }
}
```

I know there are answers on internet in case if I have to upload file on Node.js server But in my case I have to transfer file using `request` module from Node.js to PHP server.

It is working fine in case if file size is small but not if CSV file size is large.

The one thing which I have noticed that if file size is large then `if (!empty($_FILES)){}` on php side went failed. So I don't think there is issue on PHP side. Please suggest what should I modify there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem *is* on the PHP side. [The default `upload_max_filesize` configuration value for PHP is 2MB](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.sect.file-uploads). You will need to increase that value to accept larger file uploads.

Comment: are you sure ??

Comment: In app.use(express.limit(100000)); this is the way if we are uploading file on same server. But in my case requirement is different, so I have doubt that it should be on the node js side as On PHP it is 50mb size for upload

Comment: How did you verify the PHP limit? In your `actionSavetestvideo()` function, did you try outputting the result of `ini_get("upload_max_filesize")` somewhere?

Comment: I have saved again and restart server. RESTART SERVER then worked. Thanks for your help ^_^

Answer (score 1):

I agreed from mscdex the problem is on PHP side. After increasing `upload_max_filesize` from 2MB to 50MB it was not working, till then I have restarted the Apache Server again.

On Restart the Apache server, it starts working perfectly.

Comment: It seems that although the other poster gave you the answer, you reposted the same thing and awarded yourself the tick. Would you consider giving that acceptable to the other poster instead?

Comment: @halfer In actual it worked only after the restart if you will see the edit history of other post, I have posted in that but mscdex declined my edit. So I posted new answer. even I have upvoted his answer. ..well.. thanks for visiting my profile :)

Comment: Ah yes, I spotted that minor difference. It would normally be in the spirit of Stack Overflow to give the tick away anyway, but if the other poster rejected your edit then OK. They should not have rejected the edit, in my opinion - it was fine.